# ListFragment resize items to fill the screen

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I've got a ListFragment of 7 items.

I just want to know if it's possible to fill all the screen with it.

But with screen size compatibility.

something like this:

[image]

If it's not possible, is there an easiest way ?

Thx in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a LinearLayout for your problem.

Than, you can set in your XML file, that the layout should be on the whole screen:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

(You can use FILL_PARENT or MATCH_PARENT -> Its the same ;-) )